# Delete partition on external hard drive with mac os x 10.6

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, partitioning

I have an external hard drive with two partitions, both of them are clear, there is no data on them. How can I merge the two partitions together to form one again? The file system is not NTFS.

This is probably a stupid question, yet I could find nothing about it on the web :S

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use the Disk Utility(use the Spotlight to find) to delete one of the partions, then re-size the first one to occupy all of the free space.  A good tutorial on how to use the Disk Utility to resize a partition can be found [here](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1395749).

Comment: If you're having any problems using Disk Utility, then repair the drives using Disk Utility.
You can also use iPartition but for a simple case like this there's no need to pay for 3rd party tools.